# Деструктор <vector>

Tags: c++, вектор

Как правильно вызывать деструктор вектора?

```
    vector <int> x(3,2);
    x.~vector();
    std::cout << x.size(); // выводит 3, хотя объект уже должен быть уничтожен
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не должны вызывать деструктор для класса `std::vector`. Он будет вызван автоматически, когда объект класса прекратит свое существование.

Если вы хотите очистить вектор от его элементов, то вызывайте функцию-член класса `clear`

```
x.clear();
```

Comment: Мне нужно его вызывать, это невозможно что ли?

Comment: @Vladislav Вам не нужно его вызывать. Если вам нужно его вызывать, то вы делаете что-то неправильно.

Comment: У меня есть класс, в котором помимо всего прочего есть вектор. В деструкторе класса, который обязателен в моем случае, также нужно вызвать и деструктор вектора. Или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: @Vladislav Когда вызывается деструктор класса, то сначала выполняется его тело, а затем автоматически вызываются деструкторы подобъектов класса. Вам не надо вызывать явно деструктор вектора, иначе поведение программы будет неопределенным, так как деструктор для вектора будет вызван дважды: вами явно, и деструктором класса неявно.

Comment: А, так вот почему иногда аварийно завершается! Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
public:
   A () : x() {}
   ~A() {}
private:
   vector<int> x;
}

class B {
public:
   A() {x = new vector<int>;}
   ~A() {delete x;}
private:
   vector<int> *x;
}
```

В случае А деструктор для х вызывать действительно ненужно.

Comment: x = new vector<int>   это вообще компилится у вас? Я не уверен.